# 月ごとの累計の出し方について

Tags: google-spreadsheet

C列にB列の累計をsumifとrow関数を使って入れています。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",sumif(row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B),B2:B)))
```

現状だとA列の日付が3月でも4月関係なく累計金額が算出されるようになっております。

これを月が変わったら￥0からまたスタートするようにしたいです。

関数の知識が乏しいのですが、sumifの条件にmonth(B2:B)など入れたりしてたのですが、どうもうまくいかずご質問させて頂きました。
何かアドバイスをいただけるとありがたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 一行ごとに累計を出す意味は通常なくて、ほとんどは別のシートや別のセルに集約させてSUMIFを用いて表示することが多いかなと思います。こういったやり方ではだめということですかね？[参考](https://engun.co.jp/sumifs-same-month/)

Comment: keitaro_so様
コメントありがとうございます。

本来の目的を理解せずに質問していたようです。すみません。
ご提案いただいた方法で解決できるのか確認とります。
コメントありがとうございました。
また何かあればご質問させて頂くかもしれませんが、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

A列の日付が昇順に並んでいるなら以下で可能です。

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),B2:B)-SUMIF(YEAR(A2:A)*100+MONTH(A2:A),"<"&YEAR(A2:A)*100+MONTH(A2:A),B2:B)))
```